# In what scenario should we use service.Scope(), service.Transient(), service.Singleton() in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to .net core and was trying to understand when to use these service types and what could be the easiest scenario to understand the usage of these methods.

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency2>();
services.AddSingleton<IMyDependency, MyDependency2>();
services.AddTransient<IMyDependency, MyDependency2>();
```